# SOLID и полиморфизм не противоречат?

Tags: solid

Если я правильно понял, то принцип Барбары Лисков рекомендует использовать наследование только для расширения функционала, а не его замены, при этом полиморфизм позволяет изменять поведение наследников. Мне кажется, что эти два принципа противоречат. Объясните где я ошибаюсь.

Answer (score 8):

Принцип Лисков говорит не о расширении или замене функционала, а о соблюдении контракта.

Код, который работает с объектами базового класса должен работать точно также, если вы вместо этих объектов начнёте использовать наследников. При этом вы можете и расширять методы базовых классов, и заменять их — это, в общем, деталь вашей реализации, которая пользователям класса даже не интересна.

Тут, наверное, важнее обсудить, что такое *нарушение контракта*. Если говорить конкретно о методах, то у них есть входные параметры и результат. Метод без нарушения контракта не требует ничего дополнительного от входных параметров.

Например, у нас есть интерфейс коллекции со свойством `count` и методом `getByIndex()`. Индекс для получения элемента в коллекции должен быть в диапазоне от 0 до `count - 1`.

Вы придумываете коллекцию `StringUtf8`. В UTF-8 разные символы могут требовать для хранения разное количество байт: 1, 2, 3 и так далее. Ошибкой будет реализация, в которой `count` возвращает количество байт в строке, а `index` позволяет получать элементы посимвольно, потому что в этом случае нарушается контракт интерфейса.

С другой стороны, метод без нарушения контракта ничего не добавляет к выходному результату. Представим, что в коллекции есть метод `findIndex()`, который возвращает индекс элемента в коллекции, если он там есть и -1, если его там нет.

Но для отсортированного массива вы хотите возвращать место, куда можно вставить элемент, если его нет в массиве. Обычно это место возвращают в виде отрицательного числа -1, -2, -3, к которому надо добавить 1 и затем изменить знак. Такое решение тоже будет нарушением контракта.

Правильнее оставить поведение метода `findIndex()` корректным с точки зрения интерфейса, а в отсортированный массив добавить дополнительный метод с нужным поведением.